# pipを使用して、virtualenvwrapper-powershellをダウンロード

Tags: python, windows, powershell

windows powershellにおいて、pipを使用して`virtualenvwrapper-powershell`をダウンロードしようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。
pipのダウンロード自体は上手くいき、

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

と入力し、virtualenvはインストールすることができたのですが、

```
python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell
```

と入力しても`virtualenvwrapper-powershell`をインストールすることができません。
以下、エラーメッセージとなります。

```
PS C:\windows\system32> python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell
Collecting virtualenvwrapper-powershell
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true
Context object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL c
ections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwa
ng.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8.zip
    Error [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 291, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 483, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 123, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 402, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 701, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

PS C:\windows\system32>
```

お力添えいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9466

Answer (score 1):

web上からパッケージをダウンロードして、直接setup.pyを起動させる形ではどうでしょか。

ダウンロードurl（21年5月段階の最新版）

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/12.7.8

ダウンロードしたファイルを解凍し、ディレクトリ内のsetup.pyをpowershall内で
`python setup.py install`

を行えばインストールできると思われます